# How to pass parameter from spec to reporter in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine reporter, and I want to be able to pass parameters from individual specs to the reporter. For example:

the spec:

```
// I prefer this way
it("my spec 1", function() { ... }, { myParam: true });

// But this way would also be fine if it can work
it("my spec 2", function() {
    this.myParam = true;
    ...
});
```

the reporter:

```
this.specDone = function(specResult) {
   var myParam = // some way to access myParam
   ...
}
```

I haven't found any documentation for something like this, nor any example of something similar in other reporters.

I also tried debugging the flow of jasmine to see what objects get passed to each method but so far I had no luck in finding a simple solution.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one possible solution - in `boot.js`

```
var jasmineInterface = {
    it: function(desc, func, properties) {
      var spec = env.it(desc, func);
      spec.result.myParam = (properties || {}).myParam;
      return spec;
    },
...
```

and then in the reporter:

```
this.specDone = function(specResult) {
   var myParam = specResult.myParam;
   ...
}
```

of course you can (and should) make this more generic to fit other cases.